# How is this estimation so off?

Tags: nasa, photography, python, dart

Based on the recent NASA's DART mission, I wrote some code to calculate the satellite's distance and  relative velocity based on the the size of Dismorphos (the target asteroid) on the camera frame. The concept is simple:

- Filter input image and find edges on the region of interest
- Calculate the maximum diameter of asteroid on image using it's edges
- Use some basic geometry to calculate actual distance between camera and object based on its size on the frame
- Calculate average velocity between 2 distance calculations as: `(distance_measurement_1 - distance_measurement_2)/dt`

Assumptions:

1. I assume the camera of the satellite can be modeled as a pinhole camera. It's specs are described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Asteroid_Redirection_Test#Camera
   (focal length = 2.6208 m) and here: https://ssed.gsfc.nasa.gov/IPM/2016/abstracts/4043.pdf (pixel size 6.5 μm)
2. I assume the satellite is approaching the asteroid facing its longest dimension, so that the maximum length of the asteroid is visible on the frame. After a quick checkup on Dismorphos' geometry I concluded that this assumption is mostly true.

Having calculated the maximum length of the asteroid on frame, I use the following simple geometrical principle, making use of assumptions 1 and 2:

[image: Picture of pinhole camera principle and formula for calculating distance to object]

Let's call the above (1).

Dismorphos has a maximum length of *L = 177 m*. The symbol *l* is the maximum length calculated on the frame, and multiplied by the pixel size of the frame. Finally, *f* is the focal length.

The video that NASA has uploaded (https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-s-dart-mission-hits-asteroid-in-first-ever-planetary-defense-test) is - as described below it - sped up by a factor of 10, except the last 6 frames which are as the spacecraft returned them. From the last 6 frames I calculated a frame rate of 1 fps, so the rest of the video has to be around 10 fps, which means that 10 frames of video correspond roughly to 10 seconds of spacecraft movement (no need to be too accurate). For efficiency reasons in my code I calculate the distance every 10 frames, so when doing `(distance_measurement_1 - distance_measurement_2)/dt`, `dt` has to be equal to 10 seconds, because it is the time between 10 frames. **Now that the structure of the problem is set, I'll present my issue:**

[image: output of code 1]

[image: output of code 2]

These are 2 output frames I picked as examples. The calculated distance and velocity are shown on the top left corner of each image. The smaller window depicts the edges of the image after filtering. I also draw the maximum length that was calculated - on the smaller window (white line) for visualization purposes.

After some helpful comments, this is my current thought process to produce the above results: Whatever diameter I calculate in my code is measured in **pixels** on **my** screen, which is 1920x1080 (pixel size 0.16 mm). However I need the diameter (in pixels) as it would be measured by DART's frame, which is 2560x2160 pixels (pixel size 6.5 μm). Let's only keep 2160 out of 2560 pixels so that the frame would be a square (so 2160x2160). The images as NASA has published them, are 1041x1041 pixels. This means that 1 pixel of the image on my screen translates to ~2.075 pixels on DART's sensor.

Applying the above: `max_diameter_on_DART = max_diameter_on_screen*2.075`. This gives us the diameter in pixels as measured on DART's camera frame (or at least an estimation of it).

Pixel size on DART's frame is 6.5 μm (source: https://ssed.gsfc.nasa.gov/IPM/2016/abstracts/4043.pdf), so by doing `max_diameter_on_DART*6.5*10^(-6)`, I get the maximum calculated diameter of the asteroid in physical dimensions (meters) on DART's frame. Now by applying (1) i calculate the estimated distance. After that i calculate the average velocity between 2 used frames.

I expect a result close to ~6km/s for the velocity, but the estimation is still off by ~4.5km/s. This is **much** better from my previous results, but still way off.

Here are 2 tables containing all the inputs and calculations to derive my results, so one can keep track of everything:

| Inupts | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Focal length (f) | 2.6208 m |
| Pixel size (DART frame) | 6.5 μm |
| Pixel size (on my screen) | 0.16 mm |
| DART original frame size (pixels) | 2560x2160 |
| DART modified frame size (pixels) | 2160x2160 |
| My screen's frame size (pixels) | 1041x1041 |
| Pixel ratio (DART frame / my screen) | 2.075 |
| Dismorphos max diameter (L) | 177 m |
| Time between 2 frames used (dt) | 10 sec |

| Outputs | Calculation |
| --- | --- |
| Max calculated diameter on my screen (pixels) | max_diameter_on_screen |
| Max calculated diameter on DART's frame (pixels) | max_diameter_on_DART = max_diameter_on_screen * 2.075 |
| Max calculated diameter on DART's frame (meters) | real_max_diameter_on_DART = max_diameter_on_DART * 6.5 * 10^(-6) |
| Calculated distance (meters) | distance_measurement = L * f / real_max_diameter_on_DART |
| Calculated velocity (meters / sec) | (distance_measurement_1 - distance_measurement_2) / dt |

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't state the resolution of a camera in cm/px if the target is not at a fixed distance. It has an angular resolution of 0.4″/px, which you can translate to cm/px if you know the distance to the object.

Comment: There is something wrong with the number `20cm/pixel`. Doesn't this mean that each pixel is 20cm large? I doubt that the whole image sensor in the camera is 20cm large. Its probably `20microns/pixel`. This would explain the factor of 1e6. Where did you get that number `20cm/pixel`?

Comment: Note the full quote from the wiki is  "The spatial resolution of the images **taken immediately before the impact** are expected to be around 20 centimeters per pixel". You can't apply that value to images taken further away.

Comment: @OrganicMarble In fact you could if you a) scale by distance, b) know the distance of "immediately before impact" and c) know if this is purely sensor related or also influenced by optics, e.g. focus.

Comment: @AJN everything i used is listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Asteroid_Redirection_Test#Camera

Comment: @asdfex agreed, the highlighted part of the quote refers to the dependency on distance.

Comment: @asdfex this is what i don't understand. I can determine the spatial resolution of a photograph if i devide physical dimentions with the correspoinding pixels the object takes up on the frame. Why isn't that constant? What changes as i move closer or further from the object?

Comment: @OrganicMarble please refere to the comment above thisone.

Comment: @808kalli - if you take a picture of the Moon with your phone, and then take a picture of your foot, do you believe the "cm/pixel" will be the same in both images?

Comment: @808kalli According to your hand drawn diagram, what you need is the `pixel/cm` pixel density of the camera sensor. The `20cm/pixel` does **not** indicate the pixel density. To calculate (small letter) $l$ in your diagram, you need the pixel density of the camera sensor; right ?

Comment: @OrganicMarble doen't "cm/pixel" refere to the physical dimentions an object takes up on the frame? If yes then altought the moon and my foot are different sizes, they could take up the same physical dimentions on a photo

Comment: That is not what the wiki quote is describing.

Comment: @AJN exactly, i was under the impression that that is what spatial resolution meant

Comment: @AJN pixel size is 6.5µm. https://ssed.gsfc.nasa.gov/IPM/2016/abstracts/4043.pdf

Comment: @asdfex using this photo: https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/penultimate_dart_0401930049_43695_01_iof_imagedisplay-final.png i calculated a pixel density of 34.7 pixels/meter. Isn't this the value I was looking for? since i measure distance on my screen, on which the picture is 1040x1040 and not using DRACO's frame (2560x2160), I need the pixel density of the photo as it appears on my screen, correct? The 6.5µm refere to pixel density of DRACO's frame as i understand it

Comment: If you edit your question and include all the numerical inputs to your calculation and all the numerical outputs from your calculation for one of the frames, it will be easier for people to check your work. A tabular format would be nice.

Comment: What is your reason to assume that the quadratic image published by NASA is a simple scaled down version of the full rectangular sensor image? That wouldn't make sense, as their aim was to get as detailed images as possible.

Comment: @asdfex even if it isn’t, how does that affect the pixel ratio I calculated? What we know for a fact is the number of pixels on the sensor and the number of pixels of the published image.